# F# static member changes each time when accessed

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Here is a very simple class with static property:

```
[<AbstractClass; Sealed>]
type test () = 
    static member ttc = (new Random()).Next()
```

When I access ttc, it always changes... like this: (in fsi.exe)

[image: it changes...]

What is my purpose is to store values in static member:

```
type typDimTablesArray () = 
static member DimApplication        = typDimTables.DimApplication      |> Seq.toArray
static member DimApplicationState   = typDimTables.DimApplicationState |> Seq.toArray
static member DimDatetime           = typDimTables.DimDatetime         |> Seq.toArray
static member DimDbQuery            = typDimTables.DimDbQuery          |> Seq.toArray
static member DimDeveloper          = typDimTables.DimDeveloper        |> Seq.toArray
static member DimPlatform           = typDimTables.DimPlatform         |> Seq.toArray
```

But each time I access typDimTablesArray.DimDatetime.Length
It just query the database again and never store the data in the static member...

Comment: It's doing what it is supposed to do. Each time you call it you get a random number. Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do and what is your expectation. `Dispose` means getting rid of something that implements IDisposable.

Comment: I know I  could use the following code instead, but not to know what's the difference:

type test () = 
    static member val ttc = (new Random()).Next() with get, set

Comment: That's an auto-property with a backing field. If you need the static member that will do what you want.

Comment: static member means here that the property belongs to the class not any instance. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/classes) and [Fun & Profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/classes/) will give you a good overview of Classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a short example of the differences:

```
type Test3() =
    let random = new System.Random()
    let y = random.Next()
    member __.X = random.Next()
    member __.Y = y
    static member val Z = (new Random()).Next()

let x = Test3()

x.X 
x.X
x.Y
x.Y
Test3.Z
Test3.Z
```

Also, you could just create an instance of your type and pass in whatever object you need to work on. Now if it's something lazy you might need to cache it:

```
let rnd = new System.Random()
let rnds = Seq.init 10 (fun _ -> rnd.Next())

type Test4(rndsX:int seq) =
    let xx = rndsX |> Seq.cache
    member __.Length = xx |> Seq.toArray |> Seq.length
    member __.First = xx |> Seq.head
    member __.Last = xx |> Seq.last
```